# import once and use library in al pages in Flutter

Tags: flutter, vue.js, nuxt.js

In Flutter, if you want to use the library on each page, you have to write import ... many times on every page.
On the other hand, in Nuxt.js, if you write in plugins, the library can be used automatically on all pages.
Is there a way to do this with Flutter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

let's say we have a `components` directory, and there are many files, if you use those components, there will a good number of import lines. To avoid this, I create another file `export_componets.dart`, i place every imports there .

on `export.componets.dart`

```
export 'package:stack_overflow/smals/text/clearWithoutCOntroller.dart';
export 'package:stack_overflow/smals/time/timePickerss.dart';
export 'package:stack_overflow/smals/time/timmm.dart';
export 'package:stack_overflow/state/geddez.dart';
```

also you can avoid this typing using [Dart Barrel File Generator](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=miquelddg.dart-barrel-file-generator) on `Vscode`

then to use , import single one

`import 'export.componets.dart';`

Answer (score 0):

Create a plugin folder in nuxt and add a flutter.js file inside

Add flutter inside the istance of Vue.

```
/// ~/plugins/Flutter.js
import Vue from 'vue';
import flutter from 'Flutter'; // I dont know the correct import  

Vue.use(flutter);
```

After this, you can implement the plugin inside the nuxt config.

```
  // nuxt.config.js
  plugins: [
   { src: '~plugins/flutter' },
  ]
```

and you can use flutter wherever you want, without import it everytime.

If you want to read more about plugins, you can read this page: https://nuxtjs.org/docs/2.x/directory-structure/plugins